# sqlite bug: compilation error C1017 SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA

Tags: c++, sqlite, compiler-errors

I use VS2013 to compile it.

After I have upgraded to the latest version of sqlite I get this error at compile

```
sqlite3.c(14126): fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression
```

I compile sqlite with #define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA

Line 14126 have this

```
#if SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
  "ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA",
#endif
```

going back to the old version of sqlite from 2014 it gets compiled without any error. I also have tried sqlite 3.8.10 from a few months ago and still get the error.

UPDATE:
The bug was introduced with sqlite version 3.8.8 (3.8.7.2 compiles just fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's `#if` and not `#ifdef` you need to do
`#define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA 1` instead of
`#define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA`

Comment: thanks! it works now. I can award you the bounty only in 17 hours.